# boost::factory and std::function

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, std-function

I'm trying to convert some code to C++11 on gcc 4.7.2. Part of the code included the assignment of a `boost::factory` to a `boost::function`. However, the compilation fails with lots of warnings if I change it to `std::function`. Here's sample code the reproduces the error:

```
#include <boost/functional/factory.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <functional>

struct S {
  S(int) {}
};

int main() {

  boost::function<S*(int)> b = boost::factory<S*>(); // ok

  std::function<S*(int)> s = boost::factory<S*>();   // error
}
```

This gives `error: no match for call to ‘(boost::factory<S*>) (int)’`

Interestingly, if `S` takes no arguments, `std::function<S*()>` assigns to the `boost::factory` without complaint. Why doesn't this work? Is there a work around to allow assignment of a `boost::factory` to an `std::function`? I'm using Boost.1.53

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `boost::factory<S*>` insists on its argument to be bound to a reference:

```
boost::factory<S*> factory;

factory(17); // error

int argument(17);
factory(argument); // OK
```

Based on this, it seems that `boost::function<S*(int)>` passes the argument as `int` without perfectly forwarding it while `std::function<S*(int)>` seems to use perfect forwarding on the argument. As a result, the argument cannot be bound to `boost::factory<S*>` argument.

When using [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/)'s `std::function<...>` passing the argument by `const&` works:

```
std::function<S*(int const&)> factory = boost::factory<S*>();
```

Unfortunately, the same work-around does not work with the `std::function<...>` from libc++. Since you said that you tried to compile the code with gcc that may not be much of an issue, though.